# A double integral problem - polar coordinates substitution: $\int\int\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}dxdy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I need to calculate this integral:

$$\int\int\arctan{\frac{y}{x}}dxdy$$ on the area of the circle $x^2+y^2=ax$, $a>0$

here's what I did:

$x=r\cos\theta$

$y=r\sin\theta$

Substituting, we have

$r = a\cos\theta$

Now, the boundaries for $r$ are $r \in [0,a\cos\theta]$

As for the boundaries of the angle, from our condition we have that the left side is always $\ge 0$, because it's a sum of two squares. The right side must be $\ge 0$, too. Since $a>0$, then $\cos\theta \ge 0$, which is $\theta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$

Now, when I plug in my substitution into the function $f(x,y)$, I get that it evaluates to only $\theta$, since it's $\arctan{\tan{\theta}}$

I've got the integral:

$$ \large \int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \int_0^{a\cos\theta}r\theta dr d\theta$$

The integral evaluates to zero. I think I have made a mistake somewhere. Can someone point it out?

Comment: The integral is an odd function of $y$ on a region with symmetry across the line $y=0$. Why wouldn't the integral be $0$?